# Does closing xterm terminate command running on remote host?

Tags: linux, ssh, terminal, xterm

I'm using Linux a lot, but I'm confused with it. Maybe it is stupid question, but whatever.
I'v logged in `xterm` to remote host by `ssh`. Now on the remote host i started command (`rsync`, a lot of data is copied from one disk to another). I forgot to run this command in `screen`. What happens when i close xterm ? Running command terminate or not ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it does.

When you kill `xterm`, it kills [`ssh`](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man1/slogin.1?query=ssh&sec=1) (unless you specifically instructed it to detach) which, in turn, terminates connection and thus the remote shell, which kills [`rsync`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync).

You could have prevented the trouble by using [`screen`](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/), [`tmux`](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/), or [`nohup`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nohup).

You can also use [`ps`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ps) to figure out whether the process is running or [`lsof`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/lsof) to figure out whether someone is reading or writing to a particular file (which `rsync` is supposed to be copying).

Comment: i ran   $ nohup xterm&   now after re-establishing the lost ssh connection the remote host. How can I bring up the same xterm window up??

Comment: `nohup` does not work with GUI apps. You need to start `xterm` normally and run `rsync` under `nohup`.